# Life in sufficiently hot rogue planets

Tags: life, rogue-planet

The Milky Way has a bright center we can't see directly because of space dust. Are there's regions of the galaxy free of that dust that could receive all that light and radiation, right? Would it be possible to exist an 'ecosphere' around the galaxy's center where planets receive as much energy from it as the Earth receive from the Sun? Would it be possible to rogue planets orbiting the galaxy's center at that distance to sustain life?

Or it's the case that interstelar dust always blocks most energy? Even in a 'polar orbit' around the galaxy's center?

If so, how many of them could exist? More than planets orbiting stars?

Comment: I think the question of how much star-light a rogue planet would get in the center-region of the galaxy is a fair question and shouldn't be closed.   Perhaps re-worded if you don't like the wording but I think this falls under astronomy.

Comment: @userLTK can this question come under the worlbuilding website? I am not able to decide whether this question comes under astronomy or worldbuilding.

Comment: The brightness of the center-region of the galaxy is astronomy.   The type of planet might be worldbuilding.   I think it's unlikely that the center of the galaxy would have enough star-light to warm up a rogue planet to habitable zone levels, but I'm not able to say for sure.

Comment: Define "life" .   AFAIK there's no requirement that a life-form depend on irradiance.  Just ask cave-fish or    $\beta$ehemoth.

Comment: Would it be better to rewrite the question or to ask a new question and delete this one?

Comment: It is actually a neat astrophysics question. If there are $10^{10}$ stars around 1 pc away, they would in total subtend $1.27\cdot 10^{-6}$ sr, which is 2% of the Sun's solid angle so with direct light they will not be able to heat the planet. But since the dust would re-radiate starlight and hence also heat the planet (but with longer wavelengths) there might be much more IR.

Comment: Mmmm, maybe not rogue planets, but planets in a solar system like ours, distant from the star, like Mars or Jupiter moons, would be so 'hot' as Earth?

Comment: It's a completely obvious question.  OP is basically asking, is there any position (perhaps near the center of the galaxy), where there's a "fair amount of light" (like on a typical planet) even if you're just floating around as a rogue planet.